# redirect non-www to www resulting in loop address

Tags: .htaccess, no-www

I'm configuring my website to redirect any non-www to www, but resulting in address loop like this:

```
abc.com/www.abc.com/index.php/www.abc.com/index.php/www.abc.com/index.php/www.abc.com/index.php/www.abc.com/index.php ... and so on
```

Below is my .htaccess file. Can anyone help me to spot my error?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/assets|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/assets|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
                   ^---
```

You forgot to prefix the hostname with `http://`, so Apache's rewriting as a LOCAL url

Try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

instead.

It's basically the same rules that apply to:

```
<img src="www.example.com/kittens.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/kittens.jpg" />
```

Comment: my bad. it's finally working after i clear my history and cookie!